# Quantum Entanglement of Lee and Ron

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Lee and Ron are born as perfectly identical twins except for Lee being left handed and Ron being right handed. Years after birth they are seperated, Lee moving to Latvia and Ron moving to Rwanda. At one time they are both writing but suddenly God makes Ron switch his pen from his right to his left hand and continue to write perfectly. Since God has the principle of not allowing perfect "perfect" twins to exist he must at the same instant make Lee switch his pen to the other hand. Is this understanding of the result of [the Tenerife experiment](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v489/n7415/fig_tab/nature11472_F1.html) correct? Does it conform with the concept of the universe keeping books about all states, God being the book keeper, or the concept that all events/states exist at all times in parallel universes, but time only reveals a specific state/universe (like all the action in a movie is there but you can only see one scene at a time)?
Maybe I have totally misunderstood, what I have read, so please correct me (in layman terms - if possible)!

Comment: Could you give a link for a preprint for the "Tenerife" experiment?

Comment: Tenerife La Palma experiment at www.nature.com › nature11472_F1

Comment: Here is a pdf free version http://thelifeofpsi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Ma-et-al.-2012.pdf

Comment: Well, somebody totally misunderstood, for sure. :-)

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood a lot. There is no active "switching" and no bookkeeping of all states is even possible in the way you imagine. Let me refer to here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3158/ and the search button for more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is quantum entanglement?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3489/)

Answer (score -1):

> Quantum Entanglement of Lee and Ron

I'm afraid we have no evidence that Lee and Ron are in any way entangled.

> Lee and Ron are born as perfectly identical twins except for Lee being left handed and Ron being right handed. Years after birth they are seperated, Lee moving to Latvia and Ron moving to Rwanda. At one time they are both writing but suddenly God makes Ron switch his pen from his right to his left hand and continue to write perfectly.

I'm afraid we have no evidence of God either.

> Since God has the principle of not allowing perfect "perfect" twins to exist he must at the same instant make Lee switch his pen to the other hand.

I'm not keen on this analogy, but going with the flow...

> Is this understanding of the result of the Tenerife experiment correct?

It's more or less what Zeilinger et al want you to think. But that's not to say it's the correct understanding of what's really happening in this experiment. I've read this and other papers carefully, and I always seem to end up saying *huh?*

> Does it conform with the concept of the universe keeping books about all states, God being the book keeper, or the concept that all events/states exist at all times in parallel universes, but time only reveals a specific state/universe (like all the action in a movie is there but you can only see one scene at a time)?

Again I'd say that's what people want you to think, but there's no actual evidence of any bookkeeper. Or of any parallel universes. Or of any information going from A to B.

> Maybe I have totally misunderstood, what I have read, so please correct me (in layman terms - if possible)!

Perhaps we need a separate question on the "Tenerife experiment". (Which sounds like somebody is trying to talk it up, and make it sound like the Philadelphia Experiment). But until then I'd say this: people do experiments and write papers dripping with buzzwords that you don't understand, then show you a graph and make sweeping claims. Then other people in the media and around you say how wonderful it all is, and before you know it you're believing in things you can't explain. IMHO this is not scientific.