# What exactly is quantum entanglement in simple words?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

What exactly is [quantum entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) in simple words? Quantum mechanics is a fundamental theory in physics that provides a description of the physical properties of nature at the scale of atoms and subatomic particles. It is the foundation of all quantum physics including quantum chemistry, quantum field theory, quantum technology, and quantum information science.

Comment: This may help - [Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTXTPe3wahc)

Comment: This may be a useful introduction: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement

Comment: Why all the downvoting guys? People are being interested in physics; let's support them instead of being negative.

Comment: Duplicate, e.g.[this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3489/what-is-quantum-entanglement)